# how to run javascript function in selenuim

Tags: javascript, python

how i can run this js code in selenuim

```
window.hcaptcha.render = (container, params) => {
console.log(container)
console.log(params)
window.hcaptchaCallback = params.callback
}
const scriptUrl = new URL(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('script')).filter(s => s.src.includes('https://js.hcaptcha.com/1/api.js')).map(s => s.src)[0])
window[scriptUrl.searchParams.get('onload')]()
```

I tried whith driver.execute_script but it doesn't work

```
  driver.execute_script('window.hcaptcha.render = (container, params) => { window.hcaptchaCallback = params.callback }')
  driver.execute_script("const scriptUrl = new URL(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('script')).filter(s => s.src.includes('https://hcaptcha.com/1/api.js')).map(s => s.src)[0])")
  driver.execute_script("window[scriptUrl.searchParams.get('onload')]();")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use python multi-line strings with triple quotes e.g `""" .... """` or `''' ... '''`

```py
driver.execute_script("""
    window.hcaptcha.render = (container, params) => {
        console.log(container)
        console.log(params)
        window.hcaptchaCallback = params.callback
    }
    const scriptUrl = new URL(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('script')).filter(s => s.src.includes('https://js.hcaptcha.com/1/api.js')).map(s => s.src)[0])
    window[scriptUrl.searchParams.get('onload')]()
""")
```